# Optimizing conditional multiclass softmax objective function in XGBoost

Tags: python, numpy, xgboost, numba, jit

I have successfully implemented a custom multiclass softmax function function in XGBoost based on [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/c024c42dce0a2c4d01881751f0e3dc7c7691ebf8/demo/guide-python/custom_softmax.py) tutorial. The reason for customization is that the classes I want to predict are conditional on some data inputs - i.e. of the 24 possible classes being predicted, only a certain subset are valid. `valid_transitions` are lists of indices corresponding to classes we want to make predictions on and `invalid_transitions` are the inverse set of indices.

I have implemented `.fit()` and `.predict_proba()` such that they take `valid_transitions` and `invalid_transitions` as arguments which tells `softprob_obj()` and `softmax()`which classes to null out during training and prediction.

```
def softmax(x, valid_transitions, invalid_transitions):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        e = np.exp(x[i,valid_transitions[i]])
        x[i, valid_transitions[i]] = e/np.sum(e)
        x[i, invalid_transitions[i]] = 0
    return x

def softprob_obj(labels, predt, data, valid_transitions, invalid_transitions):
    '''Loss function.  Computing the gradient and approximated hessian (diagonal).
    Reimplements the `multi:softprob` inside XGBoost.
    '''
    kRows = len(data)
    kClasses = len(np.unique(labels))
    # The prediction is of shape (rows, classes), each element in a row
    # represents a raw prediction (leaf weight, hasn't gone through softmax
    # yet).  In XGBoost 1.0.0, the prediction is transformed by a softmax
    # function, fixed in later versions.
    assert predt.shape == (kRows, kClasses)

    eps = 1e-6
    # compute the gradient and hessian, slow iterations in Python, only
    # suitable for demo.  Also the one in native XGBoost core is more robust to
    # numeric overflow as we don't do anything to mitigate the `exp` in
    # `softmax` here.
    probs = softmax(predt, valid_transitions, invalid_transitions)
    labels = labels.astype(int)
    hess = np.maximum((2.0 * probs * (1.0 - probs)), eps)
    probs[np.arange(len(probs)),labels] -= 1
    # Right now (XGBoost 1.0.0), reshaping is necessary
    grad = probs.reshape((kRows * kClasses, 1))
    hess = hess.reshape((kRows * kClasses, 1))
    return grad, hess
```

This works, but is pretty slow in training, presumably because the core xgboost functions I'm replacing are not written in python. I made some attempts to try to vectorize the calculation in numpy to avoid the for loop in `softmax()`, but ran into some issues with the ragged arrays that `valid_transition` and `invalid_transition` create. Was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to optimize this within python. Thanks!